# TYPO3 news extension - show the whole article

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I'm using the news extension for TYPO3. I have a page named "News" where I want to show ALL complete news records that exist. But the article is cut with a button "Read on" which leads you to the detail page.

What do I need to do that it shows the whole article on the news page of each article that exists?

TYPO3 version: 7.6.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set TypoScript constant `plugin.tx_news.view.partialRootPath` to a path of your choice (preferrably to an extension holding your concrete site‘s configuration and assets), create a subfolder named 'List' in this path and copy file `EXT:news/Resources/Private/List/Item.html` over to the newly created folder.

Then adopt this file to your needs. Apparently, you‘d have to change stuff around [line 52](https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Resources/Private/Partials/List/Item.html#L52) to use `bodytext` only and remove the `f:format.crop`…

It‘s worth understanding how fallback in template root paths works in news and in TYPO3 in general - I suggest you [read up a bit](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/Start/Index.html) about it